# Windows Batch - Remove first word from a string

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to remove the first word from a string in batch.

Example: "this kid loves batch" to "kid loves batch"

I have tried:

```
@echo off
set /p text=text: 
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%text%") do set updated=%%a
echo %updated%
pause
```

It just outputs the first word, and does not delete the first word.

How can I make it delete the first word, and keep the rest of the string?

Comment: Use `%%b` instead of `%%a`.

Comment: @SomethingDark It gives the same output when I change %%a to %%b

Comment: No. Just change: `set updated=%%b`

Comment: If you happened to read the help file for the `FOR` command. Specifically the section about the `TOKENS` option: **If the last character in the tokens= string is an asterisk, then an additional variable is allocated and receives the remaining text on the line after the last token parsed.** The additional variable is the next letter in the alphabet to put it in simple terms. In reality it is the next ascii character but explaining that is for another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `"tokens=1,*"` with the default delimiter in a `for` loop where the variable is `%%a`, everything to the left of the first whitespace character is stored in `%%a`, while everything else is stored in `%%b`.

To get everything after the first word, simply change `set updated=%%a` to `set updated=%%b`

```
@echo off
set /p text=text: 
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%text%") do set updated=%%b
echo %updated%
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without the for loop too:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "text=text: "
Set "updated=%text:* =%"
Echo(%updated%
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Bizarre!  But how do you also extract the first word to save it separately?

Comment: @Victoria, this is even more bizarre… `Set "updated=%text: ="&:"%"`. Please however, in future do not ask new, completely different questions, as comments to other questions. If you cannot find an answer throughout our site by using the relatively good search facility at the top of the page, please submit a new question along with your own code attempt(s).

Comment: I'll have to dive back into the docs to figure that one out, like it did for the original answer. But I thought my question here was related, because the for loop solution provides both the first word and the remainder, whereas your solution in the answer only provides the remainder. Granted, the original question was only about obtaining the remainder, but the for solution provided both.  OK, the expansion for this one depends on some interesting side effects, not at all documented in the variable expansion description shown by "set /?" (I had missed use of * in earlier readings).

Comment: @Victoria, try this script for fun… 1. `@Set "string=one two three four five six"`, 2. `@SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, 3. `@For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set word[) 2>NUL"') Do @Set "%%G="`, 4. `@Set "i=1"`, 5. `@Set "word[!i!]=%string: =" & Set /A i += 1 & Set "word[!i!]=%"`, 6. `@Set word[`, 7. `@EndLocal`, 8. `@Pause`. You should see some even more interesting side effects!

Comment: Interesting, but the for line doesn't seem to contribute to the outcome, so I'm a bit baffled as to its inclusion.  The syntax of the penultimate Set line is rather interesting of course, with nested delimiters.

Comment: Oh, I guess it clears all existing word[ vars from the local environment to avoid confusing the output.

Comment: Interesting, your solution above only works if it is known that there is a space somewhere in the string.  If there isn't, nothing is removed!

Comment: The question @Victoria was about separating words in a string, and words are separated by spaces, hence the reason I used spaces to separate them! If you wanted to separate using another character, for instance the individual nodes in an IP Address, then you'd change `%string: =` to `%string:.=`. Please note however, whilst all of this may be interesting to you, each of these comments is being notified to the OP, for whom none of it is relevant, hence the reason I initially told you that you should not be asking new questions within somebody elses unrelated question.

Comment: The point being that some strings have only one (space separated) word, and it is probably desirable, even for the OP, to remove that word leaving nothing in the result. Your answer doesn't do that.  There is a cure, though, by adding a space at the end, prior to applying your answer.

Comment: Not at all, @Victoria; one word cannot be space separated, that would be two words! The question was clear, remove the first word from a string, with the two provided examples, both showing multi-word strings. It doesn't matter how much you try to justify your reason for asking an unrelated question, instead of submitting your own. The difference between the `for` loop and my answer, is that mine removes the first word and the first space which follows it; and the `for` loop removes the first word and every space and horizontal tab, which follows it. Both perform the OP's intended requirement.

Comment: Sorry, just because the provided examples showed multiple words, doesn't mean that every string to be processed will have multiple words. I _like_ your solution, and implemented it in a program, and then discovered the flaw with single-word strings, so had to fix it as outlined.  And even if multi-word strings are provided, if you wish to repeat the process of  removing additional words until none are left (i.e. parsing the whole string, word by word) eventually you will have a single word string, on which your solution as stated fails.

Comment: Look @Victoria, here we help to fix a specific issue, given code, and examples, and the answers provided satisfied that requirement. If your question differs from that of the OP, and it seems from your continued comments that it does, then submit your question, and if needed, reference this one as part of your question body, showing your attempts at solving your incarnation of a specific problem/task. Currently you are simply spamming a question the OP accepted an answer for approximately 4¾ years ago.